# Nextjs emotionjs and vercel: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: ..@emotion/cache/node_modules/stylis/dist/stylis.umd.js

Tags: next.js, emotion, vercel

Here's the message when deployed.
Code to replicate this error: http://github.com/jojonicho/next-apollo-codegen

[image: error message]

Comment: Also i don't understand the blind downvote. This is a serious problem I've been facing for days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the next.config.js file entirely.